# Sum count of query when they consist of two or more

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Select  b.PTW_MRC,DBO.r5o7_o7get_desc('EN','MRC', b.PTW_MRC,NULL, null) as Department,count(*) as CountofDept
from U5PERMITAUDIT a inner join R5PERMITTOWORK b on a.PTW_CODE = b.PTW_CODE
Where CREATED between '2016-01-01' and '2021-11-10'
and PTW_MRC = PTW_MRC--isnull(@Dept,PTW_MRC) 
and PTW_RESP = PTW_RESP-- isnull(@Auditedby,PTW_RESP)
group by PTW_MRC,DBO.r5o7_o7get_desc('EN','MRC', PTW_MRC,NULL, null)

UNION ALL

Select b.PTW_MRC, DBO.r5o7_o7get_desc('EN','MRC', b.PTW_MRC,NULL, null) as Department,count(*) as CountofDept
from U5PERMITAUDIT a inner join R5PERMITTOWORK b on a.PTW_CODE = b.PTW_CODE
Where CREATED between '2016-01-01' and '2021-11-10'
and PTW_MRC = PTW_MRC--isnull(@Dept,PTW_MRC) 
and PTW_RESP2 = PTW_RESP2--isnull(@Auditedby,PTW_RESP2)
group by PTW_MRC,DBO.r5o7_o7get_desc('EN','MRC', PTW_MRC,NULL, null)
```

[My current Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNLEH.jpg)

I want to merge the count of Dept whose departments are same.. Kindly Help!!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your query and do another group by and sum on it.

```
WITH cte_union AS
(
   Select  b.PTW_MRC,DBO.r5o7_o7get_desc('EN','MRC', b.PTW_MRC,NULL, null) as Department,count(*) as CountofDept
   from U5PERMITAUDIT a inner join R5PERMITTOWORK b on a.PTW_CODE = b.PTW_CODE
   Where CREATED between '2016-01-01' and '2021-11-10'
   and PTW_MRC = PTW_MRC--isnull(@Dept,PTW_MRC) 
   and PTW_RESP = PTW_RESP-- isnull(@Auditedby,PTW_RESP)
   group by PTW_MRC,DBO.r5o7_o7get_desc('EN','MRC', PTW_MRC,NULL, null)

   UNION ALL

   Select b.PTW_MRC, DBO.r5o7_o7get_desc('EN','MRC', b.PTW_MRC,NULL, null) as Department,count(*) as CountofDept
   from U5PERMITAUDIT a inner join R5PERMITTOWORK b on a.PTW_CODE = b.PTW_CODE
   Where CREATED between '2016-01-01' and '2021-11-10'
   and PTW_MRC = PTW_MRC--isnull(@Dept,PTW_MRC) 
   and PTW_RESP2 = PTW_RESP2--isnull(@Auditedby,PTW_RESP2)
   group by PTW_MRC,DBO.r5o7_o7get_desc('EN','MRC', PTW_MRC,NULL, null)
)
SELECT PTW_MRC, Department, SUM(CountofDept)
FROM cte_union
GROUP by PTW_MRC, Department;
```

Comment: @RafayKhan You're welcome. You can accept and upvote answer it worked to help others who stumble here.